# Change a select option by matching each value with a matching string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string `c="a"`.
I want to change my select option to the option that has the matching string.

For example my string C has a value of "a"

I want to filter through each of my options in my select element and select the option that matches with my string C

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sdavadi/NKUyh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to do this:

```
var c = "a";
$("#dropdown").val(c);
```

Comment: I spent about 2 hours trying to figure out how to filter the options using the each method. I cant believe a solution this simple skip my mind thanks alot

Comment: @user1119742 No problem! Sometimes the easy solution is the most evasive. We've all be there... :)